# Form authentication session cookie hijacking when https is used

Tags: asp.net, security, forms-authentication

**Update**

I have an ASP.NET website that uses SSL for all pages all the time.

My question is that, is it possible (practically) for someone to perform form authentication session cookie hijacking, where the form cookie id is compromised, and the target user's session is hijacked by using the compromised cookie id.

Comment: hackers is very vague. What kind of attack? Do you mean on the wire or on the client or server? That said to cut a long story short, *don't worry about it*. HTTPS and forms authentication will be plenty secure enough for pretty much everything.

Comment: What you're talking about (I hope) is session sidejacking whereby someone sniffs network packets in order to retrieve session data. SSL, if setup correctly, prevents this. Furthermore forms auth cookies are encrypted using a machine key giving it an extra later of security.

Comment: This is a good question, but you should ask it on http://security.stackexchange.com/ where experts in info sec can better answer that question. This question is unrelated to programming or ASP.NET in particular.

Comment: @Liam Sorry for the confusion. I meant form authentication cookie hijacking, where the form session cookie id is stole by other users (avoid hackers for confusion) when https is used. Is it possible.

Comment: @Heymega please refer to the comment above due to the limit by the post.

Comment: @Pingpong Stop worrying! Forms authentication adopts standard practice and is a universal standard authentication method. Https secures the transit of the cookie to and from the server. Even if a user intercepted this they wouldnt be able to decrypt it. If SSL is good enough to secure massive finacial organisations, it will be sufficient for you..Just set it up correctly!

Comment: @Heymega, There is possibility. For example, if a user's cookie (permanent or session cookie) is stole from the user's machine somehow (if ssl is not possible), the user's form session can be used by someone else.

Comment: SLL secures the transport of the session ID it doesnt prevent it from being stole from the users machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. SSL is about *encryption*; it's not about preventing access to information flowing over the wire. In other words, it's possible for anyone on the same network to inspect every single packet that goes between your server and the client. The only thing SSL does is encrypt the data in those packets so it's not viewable as plain-text.
2. SSL is great, but it's not fool-proof. Unless you've been living under a rock for the last few months, you've undoubtedly heard about the Heartbleed bug. It is particularly nasty *because* it allows a malicious user to obtain the encryption key for the SSL connection, and then, therefore, be able to unencrypt the packets that were sent. The mechanism in play is an important consideration even before the bug, though. Your SSL traffic is only as secure as your private key for your cert. If the private key gets compromised, or you allow it to leak somehow, you effectively have no security.
3. Cookies are just pieces of data that fall into the broader category of all data that gets encrypted over an SSL connection. Where they do differ is that they are stored on the client, unencrypted. If you allow the cookie to be sent over non-secure connections (HTTP), the data could leak under that circumstance. However, if you set the `Secure` flag on the cookie, then (in supported clients), it will only ever be sent back to the server if the connection is HTTPS. It's always recommended that you send this flag with any cookies that originated over HTTPS. It's important to realize, though, that the weak point of a cookie is and always will be the client. If the client is compromised, any data in stored cookies is also compromised. The level of disaster this can cause, though, is largely mitigated by *never* sending anything sensitive in a cookie, e.g. things like usernames and passwords are obviously a bad idea.
4. Cookies are domain-bound. That means that not just anyone can request them; it has to be the domain that originally set the cookie. That, then, leaves two points of compromise: on the server itself and on the client machine. If your server is compromised, exposed cookies is the least of your concerns. If the client's machine is compromised, that's outside of your control anyways. The best mitigating factor here is revolving sessions, assuming rightly that the only thing that ever comes down in a cookie is a session id. In other words, the user's session should timeout at some reasonable amount of time. This alone makes compromise much more difficult as a malicious user must catch the client's cookie when it's fresh, or the stolen data is useless anyways.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Sorry for the confusion. My question is that, is it possible (practically) for someone to perform form authentication session cookie hijacking, where the form cookie id is compromised, and the target user's session is hijacked by using the compromised cookie id.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is technically possible, but with the proper safeguarding practices the risk of this happening is very small.  The key points to check are:

- Enforce SSL
- Use an established framework or commercial product (ASP.NET forms auth, SiteMinder, etc.)
- Disable auth cookie persistence (i.e. "Remember Me" or "Save my credentials" feature)
- Enable CSRF checking (look [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) for details)
- A few more [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet).

Cookies are pretty much the industry standard for maintaining authentication session in a browser.  If you don't use them, you might as well give up on the idea of publishing a public site.